# Relation between Rowspace, Columnspace and Nullspace

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I was doing some linear algebra questions recently and noticed something interesting in the numbers, but not sure how to go about showing whether it is true or false.

Given $2$ matrices $A$ and $B$, if $rowspace(A)=columnspace(A^T)=nullspace(B)$, then $rowspace(B)=columnspace(B^T)=nullspace(A)$. I understand the relationship between rowspace and columnspace of a matrix and its transpose, but not very sure why the rowspace-nullspace relationship holds.

From Wikipedia, I see that the nullspace is the orthogonal complement of rowspace, and vice versa, as well as $X \subseteq Y \implies Y^\perp \subseteq X^\perp$, but not sure how to rigorously prove the observation (if it is indeed true). (Additionally, how would one prove the identity stated on Wikipedia?)

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the Strang's diagram [here](https://www.itshared.org/2015/06/the-four-fundamental-subspaces.html)